# Creating data.frame in in R by comparing values with list

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, if-statement, transformation

I'm trying to transform a data.frame in R by comparing its observations with values of a list. This means if the list says: "'1' is correct." Then every other value should be wrong or N.A.

As an example I created a data.frame, which contains 3 different Variables for 3 observations:

```
dat <- data.frame("Q" = c("a", "b", "a"),
                  "P" = c(1, 2, 4),
                  "R" = c("d", NA, "d"))
```

For each variable I defined a correct answer and wrote these in a list:

```
results <- list("a", 2, "d")
```

So for Variable **Q** only **a** would be correct, for **P** only **2** and therefor **d** is the correct answer for **R**. As i want to create a dataset with Dummy-Variables, the result should look like:

```
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
[1,] "Yes" "No"  "Yes"
[2,] "No"  "Yes" "No" 
[3,] "Yes"  NA   "Yes"
```

I tried to create a loop, but the result is not as expected:

```
mylist <- list()


for (j in 1:3) {
  vec <- character(3)
  for (i in 1:3) {
    ifelse(dat[i,j] == results[j], vec[j] <- "Yes",
           ifelse((is.na(dat[i,j]) == TRUE), vec[j] <- NA, vec[j] <- "No"))
  }
  mylist[[j]] <- vec
}

df <- do.call("rbind",mylist)
```

```
     [,1]  [,2] [,3] 
[1,] "Yes" ""   ""   
[2,] ""    "No" ""   
[3,] ""    ""   "Yes"
```

I am very thankful for all of your answers :)

Comment: `apply(dat,1,FUN = \(x) x==results)` gives you a useful start point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
mapply(`==`, dat, results)

         Q     P    R
[1,]  TRUE FALSE TRUE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE   NA
[3,]  TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

Or, to get your expected output, use `t`:

```r
t(mapply(`==`, dat, results))

   [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
Q  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
P FALSE  TRUE FALSE
R  TRUE    NA  TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that did exactly what i was aiming for :)

Answer (score 1):

```
out <- apply(dat,1,FUN = \(x) x==results)

out2 <- out
out2[out] <- "Yes"
out2[!out] <- "No"
```

gives

```
> out2
  [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
Q "Yes" "No"  "Yes"
P "No"  "Yes" "No" 
R "Yes" NA    "Yes"
```

Comment: A note, this is a clumsy and manual approach and there WILL be a more elegant one without the use of intermediate objects etc.

Answer (score 0):

We could just replicate the `unlist`ed `list` and do elementwise comparison

```
dat == unlist(results)[col(dat)]
         Q     P    R
[1,]  TRUE FALSE TRUE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE   NA
[3,]  TRUE FALSE TRUE
```